# Adding class to list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have nested lists and I need to style every items. Normally I would do something like this:

```
$('#myList li').addClass('myClass');
```

However, because they are nested, I need to style just text, I suppose. How do I do this with jQuery? I thied this, but it did not work:

```
$('#myList li').text().addClass('myClass');
```

Here's HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        item 1
    </li>
    <li>
        item 2
        <ul>
            <li>
                asdasd
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I NEED TO StYLE EVERY LIST ITEM

Comment: is "asdasd" the text you want to style??

Comment: Wrap the text in a span and add the class to it.

Comment: You can not add class to the text. You need to have a wrapper for it either with 'div' or 'span'.

Comment: Ahh, I was afraid I'd have to do that... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first level, direct child

```
$('#myList > li').addClass('myClass');
```

second level AND higher

```
$('#myList li li').addClass('myClass');
```

This subject is largely documented [on jquery api **selector** page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

---

Now your question has been edited : you need to style ALL list items :

**CSS**

```
li { /* will affect ALL list-items */}
```

---

Now you made it clearer :

**Wrapping what's inside the LI element**

```
$('li').wrapInner( "<span class='your-css-selector'></span>" );
```

---

Now you shown that you won't search more than a copy-paste solution :

**Wrapping what's inside the LI element but not what resides in another inner-element**

```
$('#myList li').each(function(){
         $(this).contents().first().wrap("<span/>")
    });
```

credit to [user PLS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl) copy-pasted from his comment.

Comment: I suppose I would have to wrap text manually? .wrapInner will wrap everything, including next UL.

Comment: @santa You can do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/3REp3/ But if you can modify your markup consider doing that instead of modifying the html using the js.

Comment: It's not chrismass yet, so PLEASE, do some effort and read http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/ and the other 'selector' documentation. You will find BY YOURSELF that you can wrap what you select. Something like $('selector').not(thatotherthing) ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just style text.

You can specifically style the nested list items by doing this:

```
$('ul#myList > li > ul > li').addClass('myClass');
```

This will add the `myClass` class to the item that has the text `asdasd` in your example

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your text in a span and apply class on them. When you apply class on `li` all of its contents gets impacted hence any descendants as well like nested ul under the li. Instead just wrap the texts in an element and apply class to them.

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <span>item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>item 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>asdasd</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$('#myList li > span').addClass("myClass");
```

With this you could just handle it using Css rule itself.